# how to retrieve data from the database using the has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many

I have

> message table

and

> message_pictures

table(It belongs to the message table) and what I want to do is retrieve each messsge pictures (if there is any) from the

> message_controller

.

How can I do it. I have surfed the web but found little scanty explanations on it.

This is the message class(model)

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :message_pictures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :message_pictures
end
```

This is the message_pictures class(model)

```
class MessagePicture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message, optional: true
  mount_uploader :message_pictures, PictureUploader
end
```

and this is the index method of the message_controller class

```
def index
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)#414, 449, 494
    @messages = @user.messages.paginate(page: params[:page])
    #@messages = @messages.message_pictures.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

You can see the line 4 of the index method to see the way I did mine but its not working

Comment: Please update your post with an error you get

Comment: Could you please try it by removing pagination on line #2

Comment: @martin zinovsky no error is display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you need is [`has_many ... :through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :message_pictures, through: :messages
end
```

**app/controllers/messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def index
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @messages = @user.messages.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @message_pictures = @user.message_pictures
  end
end
```

`has_many ... :through` simplifies the retrieving of "nested" children records via "SQL JOINS", of which normally you would have done it in a longer (more explicit way) like the following (which also works):

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def index
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @messages = @user.messages.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @message_pictures = MessagePicture.joins(message: :user).where(
      messages: { # <-- this needs to be the table name, and not the association name, and is why it is in plural form
        users: { # <-- this needs to be the table name, and not the association name, and is why it is in plural form
          id: @user.id
        }
      }
    )
  end
end
```

### Update: Alternative Solution

Looking back at your question, I have a feeling you'd only want `@message_pictures` that corresponds to `@messages` and not to all`@user.messages`, because I noticed you have pagination for the messages. I'll do it like this instead:

**app/controllers/messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def index
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    # the `includes` here prevents N+1 SQL queries, because we are gonna loop
    # through each `message_picture` in each `message` record (see index.html.erb below)
    @messages = @user.messages.includes(:message_pictures).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

**app/views/messages/index.html.erb** (example)

```
<h1>Messages:</h1>
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <section>
    <h2>Message:</h2>
    <p><%= message.content %></p>

    <h3>Message Pictures:<h3>
    <div>
      <% message.message_pictures.each do |message_picture| %>
        <% message_picture.message_pictures.each do |message_picture_attachment| %>
          <%= image_tag message_picture_attachment.url.to_s %>
        <% end %>
        <br>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </section>    
<% end %>
```

^ Above assumes `MessagePicture` is using `carrierwave`. P.S. It looks to me there's something wrong with how you defined your models, because your `message` has many `message_pictures`, while each of the `message_picture` also has many attached `message_picture` carrierwave attachments (assuming you used the "multiple-file" upload set up for carrierwave because you used `mount_uploader :message_pictures, PictureUploader` instead of `mount_uploader :message_picture, PictureUploader`. The model problem I think is because it's like this: `message` < `message_pictures` < `message_pictures attachments`, but (depending on your use-case), it should probably be just like `message` < `message_pictures` - `message_picture attachment`, or just simply `message` < `message_pictures attachments`

Comment: How then can I retrieve it in the template? Since I have created 2 variables. messages = user.messages.paginate(page: params[:page])
    message_pictures = user.message_pictures

Comment: All instance variables defined in the controller-action (those that start with `@`) are all accessible in the templates. So in the templates, you can just retrieve / render them via `@message_pictures`

Comment: While I tried It,  I kept receiving the same error 'The asset "" is not present in the asset pipeline

Comment: @gbengawale That's a different error. Looks like you're using carrierwave. I've updated my answer. See if that helps :)